# Can I insert a button inside a button item, and make the clicks for different reactions?

Tags: html, ionic-framework, ionic3

For my Ionic project, I want to add a "delete" button inside a button item.

There are two functions, my expectation is that openItem() is triggered when click the button item's img, and another function delete() is triggered when click the "delete" button. However, the "detele" button doesn't work for that purpose when I click it.

```
      <button ion-item>
        <ion-avatar item-start (click)="openItem(item)">
          <img [src]="item.profilepic" />
        </ion-avatar>
        <h2>{{item.befollowed_name}}</h2>
        <p>{{item.befollowed_email}}</p>
        <p>{{item.status}}</p>
        <button ion-button color="danger"(click)="delete(item)">delete</button>
        <ion-note item-end *ngIf="item.note">{{item.note}}</ion-note>
      </button>
```

Can you help how to make the "delete" button work as my expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `item-content` attribute to your delete button.
`<button ion-button item-content color="danger"(click)="delete(item)">delete</button>`

On a side note, rather than doing above solution can you just use ion-item on your uppermost container?

Then you can just add a `cursor: pointer` style in the ion-avatar, so that the cursor will change when hovering the image.

e.g.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-avatar item-start (click)="openItem(item)">
       <img [src]="item.profilepic" style="cursor: pointer;" />
    </ion-avatar>
    <h2>{{item.befollowed_name}}</h2>
    <p>{{item.befollowed_email}}</p>
    <p>{{item.status}}</p>
    <button ion-button color="danger"(click)="delete(item)">delete</button>
    <ion-note item-end *ngIf="item.note">{{item.note}}</ion-note>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: Many thanks. it works well. Can you tell how to just use ion-item on uppermost container?